# PDO fetch function error and passing variables in URL

Tags: php, html, pdo, fetch

I have come across an error trying to fetch information from my database using the PDO fetching functions. I want to fetch the last 10 ROWS but I wish to have data from all the columns, but by splitting the information up and not having it in a table.

**First error** is that I **do not** receive *ANY* output by using this code.

**Second error** is that I want to avoid that the DIV tag is being shown if there is no data from the database. By this I mean if I have **less than 10** blog posts.
Is there a statement to avoid this?

**And my questions:** Is is better to store the DIV tags in the table upon the creation than having them on the frontpage index.php file? 
*Also*, is this the correct way to pass variables through URL?

I am using this code to prepare my database, but this has not been a major trouble:

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO(ALL MY DATABASE INFORMATION);

// FETCH posts CONTENT
$fetchblog = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, post, date_add, url, pictures_url FROM posts ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 10");
$fetchblog->execute();  
?>
```

This is where I am struggeling to achive the correct information that I want...

```
<div id="blogposttitle">
    <a href="www.example.com/articles?id= 
        <?php 
        $idone = $fetchblog->fetchColumn();
        echo("$idone");
        ?>
    ">
        <?php 
        $titleone = $fetchblog->fetchColumn(1);
        echo("$titleone");
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is my content:

```
<div id="blogpostcontent">
    <?php 
    $contentone = $fetchblog->fetchColumn(2);
    echo("$contentone");
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you're missing the opening quote after `id=` in your `a` tag.

Comment: There isn't one.... its passing it in URL

Comment: My mistake. I mistook the id for something else.

Comment: Did you ensure that you're getting the expected results from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take these one at a time.

> First error is that I do not receive ANY output by using this code.

Not sure about this one. I thought I found an error in your code, but it wasn't so...

---

> Second error is that I want to avoid that the DIV tag is being shown if there is no data from the database. By this I mean if I have less than 10 blog posts. Is there a statement to avoid this?

Change your database code to:

```
$db = new PDO(ALL MY DATABASE INFORMATION);

$query = "SELECT id, title, post, date_add, url, pictures_url FROM posts ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10";
$count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ($query) as Count";

// GET NUMBER OF BLOG POSTS
$sth = $db->query($count_query);
$count = $sth->fetchColumn();

// FETCH posts CONTENT
$fetchblog = $db->prepare($query);
$fetchblog->execute();
```

Then in your HTML use:

```
<?php
if ($count >= 10) {
    $contentone = $fetchblog->fetchColumn(2);
    echo "<div id=\"blogpostcontent\">$contentone</div>"
}
?>
```

---

> Is is better to store the DIV tags in the table upon the creation than having them on the frontpage index.php file?

No. That would result in less flexibility. For example, at some point you may want to use the data in a different way other rather than just dumping it to HTML and this would cause serious problems.

---

> Also, is this the correct way to pass variables through URL?

If it works. ;o)

## Update

The problem may be that `$fetchblog->fetchColumn()` fetches the id from the first entry, then `$fetchblog->fetchColumn(1)` fetches the title from the *next* entry.

Your best bet is to put every thing in a loop and use `$fetchblog->fetchObject()` like so:

```
<?php
// loop through each blog entry
while($content = $fetchblog->fetchObject()) {

    // show title link
    echo "
        <div id="blogposttitle">
            <a href=\"www.example.com/articles?id=$content->id);\">
                $content->title
            </a>
        </div>";

    // show post
    echo "<div id=\"blogpostcontent\">$content->post);</div>";

}
?>
```

This will loop through each entry that was returned from the database. You can also access
`$content->date_add`, `$content->url`, and `$content->pictures_url`.

Since the loop ends when there are no more entries, you don't need to keep track of the number of records. So, you can go back to your original code for preparing the database.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO(ALL MY DATABASE INFORMATION);

// FETCH posts CONTENT
$fetchblog = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, post, date_add, url, pictures_url FROM posts ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 10");
$fetchblog->execute();  
?>
```

Comment: I want to show all the div tags that is available, just not the empty ones... so if I have 6 posts, I want to show those, but not the 4 empty ones...

Comment: Sorry. I have a cold today and completely misunderstood that part. Please see the **Update** section in my answer. That should solve most of your problems. Let me know.